# Control motors with Arduino using serial connection with computer

Tags: arduino, serial-port

I am working on an automated dispensing project where I intend to control ten different 12V 600mA DC pumps with an Arduino. A computer transmits messages over usb connection to the Arduino in the following form:

```
lh = pumps off
0h = pump 0 on
1h = pump 1 on
etc.
```

The Arduino gives power to the pumps by activating a TIP120 npn resistor connected to a 12V 2A DC power supply. Only one pump will be running at any given time.

When I test this by powering LEDs, the serial connection works flawlessly. However when I try it with a pump, the Arduino begins to respond sluggishly to commands, and eventually I lose serial connection with the Arduino. I can only imagine that there is some sort of power issue causing the Arduino to lose connection. Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Arduino Code:

```
#define PUMP5 5 //pin for turning transistor on/off
const byte numChars = 32;
char msg[numChars];

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600,SERIAL_8N1);
  Serial.println(msg[0]);
  pinMode(PUMP5, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  read_msg();
  command_pumps();
}

void read_msg() {
  char rc;
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    rc = Serial.read();
    msg[0] = rc;
  }
  if(Serial.available() > 0) {
    rc = Serial.read();
    msg[1] = rc;
  }
  Serial.print("msg[0]: ");
  Serial.println(msg[0]);
  Serial.print("msg[1]: ");
  Serial.println(msg[1]);
}

//PUMP5 is used for each of the scenarios since I am only testing with one pump
void command_pumps() {
  if (msg[0] == 'l'||msg[1]=='l') {
    digitalWrite(PUMP5, LOW);
  } else if (msg[1] == 'h') {
    if(msg[0]=='0') digitalWrite(PUMP5, HIGH);
    else if (msg[0]=='1') digitalWrite(PUMP5, LOW);
    else if (msg[0]=='2') digitalWrite(PUMP5, HIGH);
    else if (msg[0]=='3') digitalWrite(PUMP5, HIGH);
    else if (msg[0]=='4') digitalWrite(PUMP5, HIGH);
    else if (msg[0]=='5') digitalWrite(PUMP5, HIGH);
    else if (msg[0]=='6') digitalWrite(PUMP5, HIGH);
    else if (msg[0]=='7') digitalWrite(PUMP5, HIGH);
    else if (msg[0]=='8') digitalWrite(PUMP5, HIGH);
    else if (msg[0]=='9') digitalWrite(PUMP5, HIGH);
  }
  return;
}
```

[My Circuit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKZ0G.jpg)

Comment: What have you done on the power supply? Does it have enough capacity?

Comment: Could be the diode placement. See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/31014/where-should-i-put-the-kickback-diode-in-a-transistor-switch

Comment: Can you show us the diagram? Sounds like you are missing proper flyback diodes here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a hardware problem and belongs on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Base resistor Design

The problem can be due to the base resistor design .As shown in the figure 2 of [tip120](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/TIP120.pdf) datasheet

[image]

[image]

The required Ic is 600mA but when motor is stalled it drives more current so lets assume the value of Ic = 1250 (Please refer the datasheet of DC motor for the Max current at stalled condition). Hence Ib = 5mA (5 x 250 = 1250).which is well below the maximum of 40 mA the Arduino can put out.

we need to select a base resistor which will be low enough to ensure that the TIP120 remains saturated, but high enough to prevent the Arduino from trying to deliver more current than it should. We want a current between 5 mA and 40 mA, so let’s pick a midway point of 20 mA.

Back to Figure 2 where we see that when the collector current is 1 A, Vbe(sat) is about 1.5 V. Now if the Arduino is putting out 5 V, and Vbe is 1.5 V, that means that the resistor has a voltage drop of (5 – 1.5) or 3.5 V across it. Using Ohm’s law

[image]

A sample simulation outputs

[image]

The inductor represents the motor in sim. Attaching the  diode and capacitor will reduce the spikes